# Identify the line of a procedure of a spid/session

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017, performance-tuning

In SQL Server 2017, how can I identify or pinpoint at which line of a stored procedure a spid (session) is currently at and what the execution plan of the current statement looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The DMV `sys.dm_exec_requests` contains information about currently executing requests. However, it only returns a handle to the SQL text, you need the function `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` to get the text, and then you need to substring it.

```sql
select
  r.session_id,
  r.command,
  sql_text = SUBSTRING(st.text, r.statement_start_offset / 2 + 1, (r.statement_end_offset - r.statement_start_offset) / 2)
from sys.dm_exec_requests r
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
where r.session_id = @someSPID;
```